# How to fill a fillable word 2010 document with c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

How can I create a instance of a existing MS Word 2010 template (the template has only 1 textbox), get the fillable field and insert a string in there?

All this in c#, so far i couldn't even open a .docx document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that with those libraries:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using Vladimir.Classes_Auxiliares;
```

These fields:

```
public object Template;
public Object oFalse = false;
public Object oTrue = true;
public Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
```

And these methods. First one is to open the Word application (Visible = false), and create a new document based on a saved template.

```
public virtual Word.Document CriarDocumento(ETipoDeDocumento tipoDeDocumento, Word.Document doc, Word.Application word)
        {
            Template = tipoDeDocumento.ToString() + ".dotm";
            doc = word.Documents.Add(Template, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);


            return doc;
        }
```

The next method will look for text and objects the the content or words matches the Dictionary keys to fill the active document with values I wanted represented by the Dictionary where the key is the same as the strings in the template and the value is the new value I want to pass to the new document.

```
    public virtual void PreencherDocumentoPorObjetoETexto(Dictionary<string, string> listaDeParametros, Word.Document doc)
    {
        foreach (Shape shape in doc.Shapes)
        {
            foreach (string key in listaDeParametros.Keys)
            {
                if (shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Contains(key))
                    shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = listaDeParametros[key];
            }
        }

        foreach (string key in listaDeParametros.Keys)
        {
            Word.Find findObject = doc.Application.Selection.Find;
            findObject.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Text = key;
            findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Replacement.Text = listaDeParametros[key];

            object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            findObject.Execute(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref replaceAll, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        }

    }
```

This method will finally show the Word application in a print preview state with the print dialog opened. Only options are print or cancel.

```
    public virtual void ImprimirDocumento(Word.Application word)
    {
        word.PrintPreview = true;
        word.Visible = true;

        Word.Dialog wordPrintDialog = word.Application.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePrint];
        wordPrintDialog.Show(ref oMissing);
    }
```

This method should be called every time you open a document using those methods, it will close the document and the Word application.

```
    public virtual void FecharDocumento(Word.Document doc, Word.Application word)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        doc.Close(oFalse, oMissing, oMissing);
        word.Quit(oFalse, oMissing, oMissing);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(word);
    }
```

If you don't finish the Word application using the method above, I recommend you to call the Task Manager and finish the instance manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but I've done this with Syncfusion (on WinRT once). 
You can set a **bookmark**, then navigate to that bookmark in c# and replace its content (strings, images, tables, etc.).

http://www.syncfusion.com/

docu: http://help.syncfusion.com/winrt (**DocIO** is what you are searching for)

They have a free trial, but maybe you can find something similar (replacing bookmarks, if you can't get the fillable) for free (I didn't, but only searched for WinRT)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a free solution.

Comment: Or you could use the stuff that's built into .net. Visual Studio Tools for Office, should get you started

Comment: Oh yes I totally forgot that. The built in tools were not available for RT, that's why I had to search for something else.